# Java serialization - Android deserialization

Tags: java, android, serialization, deserialization

I have tried implementing cross platform serialization between Java and Android. I have used Serializable, and having my code in Android in the same package as in desktop Java.

Source: java-desktop serializing

```
    Student student=new Student(); 
    student.setName("John");
    student.setSurname("Brown");
    student.setNumber(776012345);

    try {
      FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("thestudent.dat");
      ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
      oos.writeObject(student);
      oos.close();
    }
      catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    }
```

Source: Android - deserializing

```
File file=new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "thestudent.dat");

    try {

      FileInputStream fint = new FileInputStream(file);
      ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fint);
      Student stud=(Student) ois.readObject();
      ois.close();
    }
      catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

}
```

Student is a class, which implements Serializable. On desktop I serialize instance of student to "thestudent.dat". I put this file on SD card at Android device and I am trying to deserialize it. I am getting error **java.lang.ClassCastException: javaserializace.Student**. But why? I have same package when serializing, same package when deserializing. All what is different is project name. Do you see any solution?

Edited - source of Student class:

```
public class Student implements Serializable {

private String name;
private String surname;
private int number;
private char gender;
private int age;
private long rc;
private int id;

public Student(){
    ;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public char getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public void setGender(char gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public long getRc() {
    return rc;
}

public void setRc(long rc) {
    this.rc = rc;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public void setNumber(int number) {
    this.number = number;
}

public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}

public void setSurname(String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
}

}
```

Comment: Can you also post `Student` class?

Comment: Are they in a package? And are you sure it is really he exact same class?

Comment: You should have a `serialVersionUID` if nothing else. Also, why not just use JSON/etc?

Comment: yes, it has the same class name...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917847/serialization-performance-and-google-android/2918007#2918007

Comment: I have read about it, but still I don't get it. Same package, same name - but error...

Comment: 2 Dave Newton - I am just trying to think about it, if it's possible or not...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am certain that two versions of Student on Both sides are not same.

Because the exception is

java.lang.ClassCastException: javaserializace.Student.

which indicates that Java has successfully deserialized the object but while typecasting it to Student on receiver side, it is throwing exception because types are not same.

A quick way to debug this is to invoke  **getClass()**   on received Student object and  **getName()**  on Student class on receiver. I am sure that in this case both are different.

And solution will be to ensure that Student on receiver side is of same type.

Comment: Right... theye weren't the same, but they should be. I have to completely rework this deserialization task. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem with the code you post. My guess is that `Student` is not in the same exact package on both sides. So if it is "com.acme.Student" on desktop, it should also be that on Android.

Also its good idea to add `serialVersionUID` in case your `Student` changes in the future.

Comment: Thanks, they are in the same packages... that's why i have written here.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using something like [Kryo](http://code.google.com/p/kryo/) or [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) for your serialization. It would be much faster with smaller payload. The only downside is that you need to include an additional jar.