# Can a serialized file created by a program be placed into an Android project and then be read there?

Tags: android, eclipse, serialization

I'm a newbie to Android development and I was wondering if I could create a serialized file (or any file) by a non-Android program and then just move it into an Android project in Eclipse and read it there? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As long as you've got the proper de-serialization code on the android side, yes.  There shouldn't be any issue here.

See:

[Java serialization - Android deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528342/java-serialization-android-deserialization)

For potential pitfalls.