# Can an Android studio app read a data-class serialized by a Java desktop app?

Tags: java, android, serialization, io

I am working on an app that utilizes a desktop-side editor for content.

If I were to serialize the necessary data-classes from the editor... would I then be able to de-serialize them Android-side?

(Assume the serialVersionUID is identical and the Android data class is a copy-paste of the one utilized in the editor)

Comment: Yes, sure why not?

Comment: @Oleg Well it seems like it _should_ but I wasn't sure so I thought I'd ask (especially since there wasn't a definitive answer or concise question about this on SO that I could find).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visit [Java serialization - Android deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528342/java-serialization-android-deserialization) for some more information. It seems that it's possible to deserialize desktop-sided serialized Java Objects if you implement the class on both sides exactly the same.

Comment: Ah, I didn't find this question when I was searching before. This is helpful.